# How to find the entry point in javascript application

Tags: javascript, entry-point

How can we find the very first javascript statement that gets executed in any web page.. I mean how can we find the entry point for any javascript application no matter what type of JS libraries / frameworks it uses?

Comment: Check the first script tag reference in html page.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015836/why-doesnt-javascript-need-a-main-function

Comment: @DouglasDaseeco arguably function declarations are *statements*. But I agree there are edge cases to take into account (only '[type*=javascript]', not defer|async|empty and probably some others. But the real question here is why do one need to know that ?

Comment: @Kaiido ... simply because I want to debug a javascript application and I want to explore the overall application architecture and function calls and I want to start from the very beginning step by step

Comment: Then it doesn't need to be programmatic. You can read the source code.